# order number alphabetically

Tags: android, sqlite

In my database sqlite I have a column with float numbers and times stored as strings, why when I try to order them with this query

```
select... order by cast("+filter+" as real)
```

return my numbers column with this wrong sequence:

```
    22,5
    23
    23,5
    23
    23,5
    24,5
    24
```

or my times column also with this wrong sequence:

```
00:56
00:57
00:52
00:46
```

Comment: have you tried to order them without casting them to real, order them as strings might work

Comment: So you've two non-string data types in a string column. Were you having a bad day? Should 45:24 come before or after 45.24?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select... order by cast(replace("+filter+",',','.') as real)
```

Sqlite expects dot, not comma, as a fraction part separator. It also silently ignores unconvertable tail, so '24,5' is converted to 24.0.

As of your times column, it will be sorted well if you sort it as string, without casting to float. But if you want to cast it for some reason, you may turn colons into dots with `replace`.

Comment: yes, order by "+filter+" asc" without cast orders my times and float columns well but not the others columns I have with int (always stored as string) they show this sequence: 10, 11, 12, 9... In my virtual device I have the float column with point, but in my real phone point becomes comma.

Comment: Why store integers as strings? (If sqlite integer is too narrow, there's also bigint which could be enough for you). Well, I think you got what I mean: use different casts (if any) for different columns, and if you cast to float, fix a separator with replace.

Comment: thank you Anton, I will try to change all my project to manage int instead of strings.